# Why failing to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows with many HDs in Asus X550JX?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, asus

I bought 240 GB SSD last week then installed Windows 10 in it. Plus I have ejected my cd rom and put my previous 1 TB HDD in its place. So I won't be able to use my cd rom for the rest of the time.

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along with windows 10. My laptop (Asus X550JX) has a really complex BIOS/UEFI menu that I don't even know if it's a BIOS screen or not, plus the technical service doesn't even know the answer.

But when I plug the USB and restarted the laptop, it automatically starts windows 10. After some operations in in BIOS(?) screen, it somehow starts asking if I want to install, but if I miss some little details in the blue screen, it might not start windows. But I can rescue computer from disabling windows' booting.

Anyways, after I managed to start installing with some suffering, I thought everything was fine. But then in the middle of the installing, an error occures and everything's gone. The error is

```
the grub-efi package failed to install into /target/ ubuntu 16.04
```

I did some research on it, used different methods and installed at least 5-6 times. But it's still not happening.

Ubuntu: 16.04
Dual-boot: Windows 10
Hardware: Asus X550JX
HDs: 240 GB SSD (Windows 10), 1 TB HDD

Comment: Are you sure that you have grub2 in your laptop? It may be just grub, since my Zenbook of 2015 has just grub. Please, correct the tag if you have grub.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible causes of your problem, and different solutions depending on the cause. The solution that's most likely to work is:

1. Download the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and copy it to a USB flash drive, as described in its `README-flashdrive.txt` file.
2. Enter your firmware setup utility and disable Secure Boot. (See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) for some examples of how to do this -- note that details vary greatly from one computer to another.)
3. Boot to the rEFInd USB flash drive and use it to boot Ubuntu.
4. In Ubuntu, install rEFInd by using the PPA or Debian package, as described in the rEFInd documentation.
5. If desired, you can re-enable Secure Boot; however, chances are good you'll need to jump through some extra hoops, as described on the [rEFInd Secure Boot page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html)

There are numerous variants on this procedure, and depending on the exact nature of your problem, the preceding procedure might not work -- but at least this procedure has a very high probability of working if you get as far as booting into Ubuntu. The other major option is to try to get it working with [Boot Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but at least one likely reason why you ran into problems would make Boot Repair fail or create new problems, too, which is why I don't recommend you poke around with Boot Repair just yet. (FWIW, that reason is an activation of your Compatibility Support Module, or CSM, as described [in this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) It's gotten to the point where the CSM causes more problems than it solves, IMHO.)

Comment: thank I forgot to add that it's solved. The reason was, windows 10 was installed in legacy mode, so i had to remove it than used UEFI boot on both windows and ubuntu, followed some partition guides, then everything's fine